# My new laptop won't let me play any songs I download

Tags: itunes, windows-media-player

I recently got a new laptop.

I reinstalled everything because my old computer is loaded with viruses. I downloaded a song to play on iTunes but it just will not play.

I tried it with Windows Media Player and it just says it encountered a problem while playing the file.

It's the same with every kind of media player on my laptop. It can only play the sample music provided in the laptop, and it plays music and video fine online.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Which version and edition of Windows? What other media players do you have installed? What else could you have installed to interfere with the media (for example, codecs)? What was it exactly that you downloaded? An MP3? A WAV file?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to play an older AAC file without iTunes installed? Randolph's questions do need answering though.

Comment: its already in my laptop when i got it..just WMP. i've got itunes, quicktime player and GOM player. i got the GOM encoder but i don't really use it though. the file i downloaded is an mp3 file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and see if the file plays in that. If so, it's a codec problem. If not, it's a deeper problem and may be related to your soundcard drivers.

EDIT: The file you downloaded may be corrupt.

Comment: ok, so i tried with VLC player and it shows me this:VLC can't recognize the input's format:
The format of 'file:///C:/Users/ryuuko/Music/kellyclarkson-alreadygone-clean.mp3' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.

Comment: Is this only with one file, or have you tried with other MP3s? It looks like the file is corrupt.

Comment: oh yeah, its the file...lols. thanks! now i can finally play songs^^